# finding change of coordinate basis using identity function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

I want to find the change of coordinate matrix using $[I]_{\beta^{'}}^\beta$  that changes ${\beta^{'}}$ coordinates into ${\beta}$ coordinates.

$${\beta^{'}}=\{(0,10),(5,0)\}$$
$${\beta}=\{(-1,3),(2,-1)\}$$

I don' have any problems writing a linear transformation as a matrix when the basis are the standard basis but when the basis are not standard then I seem to be getting the wrong answers.

I computed $[I]_{\beta^{'}}^\beta$ by first computing the identity function with respect to $\beta^{'}$ and got

$$I(0,10)=(0,10)$$
$$I(5,0)=(5,0)$$

Then when I try to write these vectors in with respect to $\beta$, similar to how I  would with respect to the standard basis I get

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    30       & -5 \\
    -10      & 10\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that $A(A^{-1}B)=B$, with $A$ having the basis vectors of $\beta$ as columns, and $B$ having basis vectors of $\beta'$ as columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are getting that final matrix. The first column should be the vector $(0, 10)^T$ written in terms of the basis $\beta$ and the second column should be $(5,0)^T$ written in terms of the basis $\beta$.

In other words, to obtain the first column, you are looking to solve the following vector equation

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix} = a \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

This is equivalent to the system of equations

$$
\begin{align}
&0 = -a + 2b \\
&10 = 3a - b
\end{align}
$$

Solving this I get $a = 4$ and $b = 2$ so the first column in the transition matrix is $(4,2)^T$. The second column is found analogously.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find $[I]^e_\beta$ - the change of co-ordinate transformation from $\beta$ to $e$, the standard basis - and the transformation $[I]^e_{\beta'}$ from $\beta'$ to $e$, then you can compose them, just remember that  ${[I]^e_{\beta'}}^{-1} = [I]^{\beta'}_e$.